# Subsetting while working with list, dataframe and matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe, subset

I have three form of data.

a data frame, `info.data` as

```
id.num <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35) 
id.name <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fifteen", "twenty", "tyone", "tytwo", "tythre","tyfive", "thrty", "thrtyone", "thrtytwo", "thrtythree", "thrtyfour", "thrtyfiv") 
info.data <- data.frame(id.num, id.name) 
row.names(info.data)<- c("x1","x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12", "x13", "x15", "x20", "x21", "x22", "x23", "x25","x30", "x31","x32", "x33", "x34","x35")
```

a matrix, `mat`, with some common rownames as `info.data`,

```
mat <- matrix(c(sample(0:1, 100, replace=T)), nrow=10, ncol=10)
diag(mat)<-0
t2 <- lower.tri(mat)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[lower.tri(mat)]
row.names(mat) <- c(paste("x",3:12,sep=""))
colnames(mat)<-c(paste("x",3:12,sep=""))
```

and a `list`, `req.l`, with some common `id.names` of `info.data`.

```
req.l<- list(L1=info.data$id.name[2:8],LL1=(info.data$id.name[1:5]),LLL1=(info.data$id.name[8:21]))
```

i wan to choose a list, say `LL1`, and subset corresponding matrix from `mat` (whichever values are present) such that the output would be a subset (with corresponding list values as col/row names) be following,

```
          three four  five
three        0      0     1
four         0      0     0 
five         1      0     0
```

I tried using `%in%` in couple of lines as a result the code getting lengthy. Further, I need to change the list name etc. every time, which is creating confusion, which in turn making my brain to stop !!
is there a neat way to do such task? can `grep` be used in such situation?

Answer (score 2):

There have to be better ways, but this seems valid too:

```
lapply(req.l, 
       function(X) {
          tmp = rownames(info.data)[match(X, info.data$id.name)]
          dmnms = replicate(2, as.character(X[tmp %in% unique(unlist(dimnames(mat)))]), simplify = F)
          ret = do.call("[", c(list(mat), 
                               lapply(dimnames(mat), 
                                         function(x) 
                                            na.omit(match(tmp, x)))))
          dimnames(ret) = dmnms
          ret
       })
#$L1
#      three four five six seven eight
#three     0    0    0   0     0     1
#four      0    0    1   0     0     0
#five      0    1    0   1     1     0
#six       0    0    1   0     1     1
#seven     0    0    1   1     0     0
#eight     1    0    0   1     0     0
#
#$LL1
#      three four five
#three     0    0    0
#four      0    0    1
#five      0    1    0
#
#$LLL1
#       eight nine ten eleven twelve
#eight      0    0   0      1      0
#nine       0    0   1      0      1
#ten        0    1   0      1      1
#eleven     1    0   1      0      1
#twelve     0    1   1      1      0
```

Comment: Thank you alexis ! This is really neat.

Comment: could you help me with a followup question?

Comment: @Polar.Ice : I'm not sure I understand your comment. What question are you refering to?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I thought of asking the question but later changed my mind. Sorry, i forgot to delete my query. 

Actually, i was having problem in applying the code to a situation when the info.data$id.num has values as c("one-001", "one-003", "one-015", "two-011", ......). I used substr command to compare the values of L1, L2 (without additional -001, -002 etc). Again, its a bit lengthy, but it think its working ok. I would appreciate if you could provide another neat help though :)

Comment: @Polar.Ice : Hm, maybe I'm missing something, but if you want to extract the "lettery" part of `x`, `x = c("one-001", "thirtytwo-021")`, you could `unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", x)))`. Also, I don't know how you used `substr`, but it should be better to use it outside of any `_apply` since it is vectorised and, potentially, fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to jump through here, but let's break it down

First, we need to find the rows in info.data for the values in the list we choose. We can do that with

```
info.data$id.name %in% req.l[["L1"]]
```

now we need to find the row names those values correspond to because those are the names in the matrix.

```
rownames(info.data)[info.data$id.name %in% req.l[["L1"]]]
```

does that. Now we want only those names that are also in the matrix, so we'll just take the overlapping values

```
intersect(
    rownames(info.data)[info.data$id.name %in% req.l[["L1"]]], 
    colnames(mat)
)
```

This is finally the list of rows/cols we want from mat. Now we can subset

```
mc <- intersect(
    rownames(info.data)[info.data$id.name %in% req.l[["L1"]]], 
    colnames(mat)
)
mat[mc,mc]
```

And then we need to rename the dimensions so here we do back to the data.frame to get them

```
out <- mat[mc,mc]
dimnames(out) <- replicate(2, info.data[mc,"id.name"], simplify=F)
out
```

And since this was all based off the string "L1", you can easly replace that value with ever you want or a variable.